# display google forms in webview using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to open a google form in a `WebView`. 
I write the form in English but when I embed it in my app the page displays in Arabic(?) and the text goes from the right to the left. Why?

[image]

*my xml code:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.user.webview.feedback">
<WebView
android:id="@+id/link_webview"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

*Java*

```
public class Feedback extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView feedbackformlink;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feedback);

        setTitle("Your Feedback");

        feedbackformlink = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.feedback_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = feedbackformlink.getSettings();

        feedbackformlink.setInitialScale(200);
        feedbackformlink.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        feedbackformlink.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        feedbackformlink.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        feedbackformlink.loadUrl("https://google form .. share link");
        feedbackformlink.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (feedbackformlink.canGoBack()){
            feedbackformlink.goBack();
        } else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Arabic the language you use for google in or the one you Android device is set up with?

Comment: google and mobile device i use English language

Answer (score 0):

Apply this below code inside OnCreate Method of Activity! No need to use Any Tag of WebView in XML.
Hope it works.
..........................

```
  WebView  mWebview  = new WebView(this);

    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

    final Activity activity = this;

    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
            // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
            onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
        }
    });

    mWebview .loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/forms/ ... link");
    setContentView(mWebview );
```